# Is it safe to add new features to production SQL Server Instance

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I need to add `Integration Services Catalogs` to our production instance of SQL Server 2008 in order to automate some SSIS packages. It wasn't included in the original installation 5 or 6 years ago.

`Is there any danger in adding new features to the production server?`

We have backups in place, but I would prefer to find a different automation solution if there is a probability that the data could become corrupt.

I would follow the steps from this post if I were to install the additional feature-
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14551255/how-do-i-enable-integration-services-ssis-in-sql-server-2008

****EDIT****

I realized that Integration Services Catalogs isn't available for SQL Server 2008. So the link I posted is irrelevant. I'll leave the question up in case anyone has valuable input regarding adding features to existing SQL Server instances.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only danger I would say is installing new features that require the database engine service to get taken down when you don't expect it to be taken down.

Other than that, adding new services to an old instance isn't dangerous on its own. I have added reporting, analysis, and integration services post install plenty of times over the years without any unforeseen issues.

Comment: Thanks for the input. It's nice to hear that you've done it multiple times without any problems.

Answer (score 2):

Be sure and apply any Service Packs or CUs to bring SSIS up to date with your database engine installation.